# product images/icons for printing company?

Tags: icon, images, stock-images, print-production

I work for a printing company, and our webshop is missing icons/images for our products.
So, I've finally convinced my bossman to buy a pack, but we really can't find any...
here are a few examples of icon packs we're looking for.

http://www.printdeal.be/nl/producten/overzicht

http://www.zwartopwit.be/shop/all <== this one is truly awesome and uniform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me it is not icons you want, but product images. You can either take the pictures yourself, but for professional images you want to buy *images* not icons. There are a plethora of sites dedicated to this. Shutterstock is just one: http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-53306749/stock-photo-graphic-designer.html

If it is actual *icons* you want, I would recommend **[Icomoon](http://icomoon.io/).** They have professional packs of icons you can buy, or you can use the free options.

Comment: you're right! all this time I was searching google for "icons" that's why I wasn't able to find anything... I got these on shutterstock: http://www.shutterstock.com/s/print+mock+up/search.html?page=2&thumb_size=mosaic

Comment: There you go. Happy days :) Glad to be of help.